# Converting from TIFF to ESCP2

Tags: cups, epson, escp

I am trying to develop a printing interface for my epson printer that will be used in a .net project. I need to convert any known format (maybe pdf, tiff, even jpeg) to epson ESCP/R format.

I made my research.
There is some ways. For example : Ghostscript Uniprint (Deprecated)
There is no information about why its deprecated and how can i use it.

There is another way but in linux side. CUPS filters
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:CUPS-block-diagram.svg#/media/File:CUPS-block-diagram.svg
on this diagram there is a line.

Anybody knows any way ?

Comment: why do you want to write ESCP/2 from within windows? windows provides printer drivers and API to use them for a reason

Comment: I need to make some changes on prn file programmatically. How can i grab the data other way